# How to achieve High Availability in GCP MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I want to achieve `High Availability` in `Google cloud platform`.
I have 1 instance of `MYSQL5.7` with following configuration:

```
Database version is MySQL 5.7
Auto storage increase is enabled
Automated backups are enabled
Point-in-time recovery is enabled
Located in us-central1-c
No database flags set
No labels set
Highly available (regional))
```

Now I am very confused because I follow this Link

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha#ha-existing

and enable `High Availability` by simply selecting the `High availability (regional) checkbox`. But I am confused is it working or not according to this link in order to test this setup I have to go through the `stackDriver` I also did it but not getting any response. Also I want to know do we need 2 instance of `sql` in order to achive `HA` or do I need to create `replica of instance` please help.

Comment: Have a look at the https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha#verifying_an_instance_has - looks like you've already turned it on and it's already `Highly available (regional)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already select "Enable high availability" you don't need to do anything else. As you can see in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability); when you enable it, Google automatically creates a secondary instance named "standby instance" in another zone, different from us-central1-c in order to create a failover cluster, the idea is that in case of a failure in the "Master instance" the secondary will be able to stand up as the main one with the same configuration as master instance due the synchronous replication.